# How to get JSONP data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I have a file on the a external domain with the following JSON format:

```
{"image":"http:\/\/magazine.domain.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/festival_home-240x122.jpg","link":"http:\/\/magazine.domain.com\/category\/fashion\/forget-the-mud-festival-fashion-essentials\/","title":"FESTIVAL FASHION ESSENTIALS","description":"What to wear at festivals is a perennial problem for music lovers, follow our fashion guide and be the best dressed moshing in the mud this summer!"}
```

I need to get the data using JSONP and have changed the format to:

```
jsonCallback ({"image":"http:\/\/magazine.domain.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/festival_home-240x122.jpg","link":"http:\/\/magazine.domain.com\/category\/fashion\/forget-the-mud-festival-fashion-essentials\/","title":"FESTIVAL FASHION ESSENTIALS","description":"What to wear at festivals is a perennial problem for music lovers, follow our fashion guide and be the best dressed moshing in the mud this summer!"});
```

I am using jquery 1.3.2, I cannot upgrade this at the moment and have tried the following:

```
var url='http://magazine.domain.com/test1.js?callback=?';

$.getJSON(url, function(data){
 console.log(data);
});
```

I get the following error - Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonCallback is not defined.

Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `jsonCallback` with the value of the `callback` query string parameter.

Comment: That changes each time, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `<?php header('application/javascript'); echo $_GET['callback']; ?>( /* data data */ );` (for example, if you were to use PHP).

Comment: thanks unfortunately I do not have access to the code file that generates the HTML just the javascript.

Comment: Javascript creates the json? that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user2025749 — What HTML? That's code that can generate the JSONP response.

Comment: What i meant was I only have access to js files so I cannot add any php/java (in my case) anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url='http://magazine.domain.com/test1.js';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp', // <-- jsonp
    success: function(resp) {
        // resp == {"image":"http:\/\/magazine.domain.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/festival_home-240x122.jpg","link":"http:\/\/magazine.domain.com\/category\/fashion\/forget-the-mud-festival-fashion-essentials\/","title":"FESTIVAL FASHION ESSENTIALS","description":"What to wear at festivals is a perennial problem for music lovers, follow our fashion guide and be the best dressed moshing in the mud this summer!"}
    }
});
```

Comment: @user2025749 Then you will need to figure out what the callback parameter is called, defaults to &callback=... But some services calls it &jsonp=... or ?wrap=... etc.

Comment: @user2025749 Also if you are running on the same domain as the service don't use jsonp use native ajax request and fetch the json that way. `dataType:'json'`

Comment: It is on a different domain :-(